# How do I pass parameters from angular controller/service, to server route, to query database?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to pass parameters to my backend route that will query my database to find the appropriate information, without having to write duplicate code for hundreds of different items. My problem is: I'm only getting an empty array returned; no errors. Any thoughts?? Here is some code:

Data in Mongo:

Materials Collection

```
{"material_name": "Something"},
{"material_name": "Another Something"}
```

server/route:

```
app.get('/materials/:name', (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.name) {
        db.collection('materials').find({"material_name": req.params.name}).toArray(function(err, results) {
            res.json(results);
        });
    }
});
```

factory:

```
angular.module("marbleApp")

.factory('materialFactory', function($q, $http) {
    return {
        getMaterialStuff: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            httpPromise = $http.get('/materials/:name');

            httpPromise.success(function(materials) {
                deferred.resolve(materials);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log('Error...');
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

controller:

```
.controller('MatInfoCtrl', function($scope, materialFactory, $stateParams) {
    $scope.materialStuff = {};
    materialFactory.getMaterialStuff()
    .then(function(materials) {
        $scope.materialStuff = materials;
        console.log(materials);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    $scope.name = $stateParams.materialName;
    $scope.category_name = $stateParams.categoryId;
});
```

state:

```
.state('material', {
    url: '/materials/:name',
    templateUrl: '/public/views/partials-matInfo.html',
    controller: 'MatInfoCtrl'
  });
```

EDIT: Here is the route I'm using to query mongodb. I slipped a console.log in the, and the result is 'undefined'....
Any ideas why?? Something is obviously not connecting/being passed.

```
app.get('/material/:name', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('materials').find({"material_name": req.params.name}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(req.params.name);
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request always asks for `/materials/:name`, it should replace `:name` with the actual name:

```
httpPromise = $http.get('/materials/:name');
```

Comment: httpPromise = $http.get('/materials/thename');  Is that what you mean?

Comment: another way of doing it would be: $http.get('/materials/', { params: { 'name': yourNameHere } }).  The benefit of using the config object, is that angular encodes the parameters for you.

Comment: the only reason I can't hard code the 'yourNamehere' is because I have too many materials, hundreds, which would require soo many routes/services. I was looking for something along the lines of a wildcard variable...

Answer (score 0):

when you will send a request to server for path `app.get('/materials/:name'` then you should call from your service with your name value instead of `:name` like `$http.get('/materials/yourName')`

you can follow :

In your controller

```
$scope.name = $stateParams.materialName;
materialFactory.getMaterialStuff($scope.name).then(function(response){
    console.log('success', response.data);// check success data
    //rest of code
}, function(response) {
   console.log('error', response.data);// check error data
})
```

and in your service/factory:

```
getMaterialStuff: function(name) {// get name from controller
    return $http.get('/materials/'+name); // used name
    //By default $http return promise so no need to use $q.defer()
}
```

server route:

```
app.get('/materials/:name', (req, res) => {
    console.log('param name =', req.params.name); // check request params name
    if (req.params.name) {
        db.collection('materials').find({"material_name": req.params.name}).toArray(function(err, results) {
            if(err) {
               return res.status(400).send(err); // if error return with error data
            }
            return res.status(200).send(results);// if success return result
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried this code you suggested, and it gives the error:
Error... Cannot GET /materials/
Would that possibly be a problem with the different states I have set up, or the ui-sref link on the element I'm trying to click?

Comment: EDIT to my previous comment... Instead of an error, I am now getting an empty array returned, and in the console getting an 'undefined' message... code is still the same as what you suggested above. Any ideas why the GET request is returning empty array and undefined message?

Comment: getting an empty array means no document found for that name. Bydefault `$http` return promise so no need to use `$q.defer()`. Updated my answer can you check now?

Comment: That update seems solid, but I am still getting "param name = undefined". Could it be that $scope.name is being passed as undefined and not as the intended material name??

Comment: yeah can be so check please `$scope.name` also where else used :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I wasn't passing the material_name as a variable to be used by the controller, which then could be used as a parameter in the route/GET to database.

I used a ui-sref:

```
 <div class="col m3" dir-paginate="material in graniteStuff | itemsPerPage: 20">
          <a ui-sref="material({name: material.material_name})">
```

Then changed my controller to:

```
$scope.name = $stateParams.name;
    materialFactory.getMaterialStuff($scope.name)
```

Then passed that to my service:

```
getMaterialStuff: function(name) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            httpPromise = $http.get('/material/' +name);
```

Which then passed the parameter to the route:

```
app.get('/material/:name', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('materials').find({"material_name": req.params.name}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(req.params.name);
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes, your answer was correct on the backend and controllers. But I didn't show you the html view code, and that's where the problem was. I was failing to access the material_name property, and therefore name was being passed undefined. Putting ({ name: material.material_name }) into the code solved that problem.